# Find the Closest Double Palindrome

Tags: code-golf, palindrome, bitwise, floating-point

Given a double-precision float, find the closest double-precision float whose binary representation is a palindrome.

## Input

A floating point number `x`. You may use any format you like for input, but the format you chose must be able to represent every possible IEEE 754 binary64 value, including denormals, distinct representations for `+0` and `-0`, and `+Inf`, `-Inf`, and `NaN`.

## Output

A floating point number `y`. You may use any format you like for output, with the same restrictions as the input format.

## The Task

`y` is any value such that:

- The IEEE 754 binary64 bitstring for `y` is a palindrome. That is, the first 32 bits are the reverse of the last 32 bits.
- `abs(x-y)` is minimal by the `totalOrder` predicate.

## Notes

- `abs(x-y)` must be computed with strict IEEE 754 double-precision floating point arithmetic.
- `totalOrder` puts non-numeric values and signed zeroes in this order: `- NaN < -Inf < -1 < -0 < +0 < +1 < +Inf < +NaN`. Otherwise it behaves like the normal `<` operator.
- The rules for performing arithmetic on non-numeric values can be found [at this website](http://www.iki.fi-jhi.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/infnan.html)
- For an overview of how binary64 floats work, [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).
- If there is more than one value for `y` that satisfies the conditions, output any one of them. Note that this can only occur if `abs(x-y1) == abs(x-y2)`, or if they are both `NaN`.
- The input and output formats may be different if desired; both formats still need to obey all the rules.
- It may be convenient to use a raw binary format for IO; this is permitted.
- For the purposes of this challenge you may consider all `NaN` values as equivalent, since `NaN` payload behavior is implementation defined.
- It is **not sufficient** to just mirror the first 32 bits. See test cases 2, 4, 5, and 7 for examples.
- Any non-`NaN` double palindrome is valid output for x=`+Inf` or x=`-Inf`, since the distance is still just `+Inf`. Reversing the first 32 bits would not be correct though since the resulting `NaN` value would have a distance of `+NaN > +Inf` from the input.
- A `NaN` though, any double palindrome would be correct.

## Test Cases

```
Input:  0x8A2B_7C82_A27D_6D8F = -1.1173033799881615e-259
Output: 0x8A2B_7C82_413E_D451 = -1.1173031443752871e-259

Input:  0x5000_0000_0000_0001 = 2.3158417847463244e+77
Output: 0x4FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFF2 = 2.3158417847463203e+77

Input:  0x5000_0000_0000_0002 = 2.315841784746325e+77
Output: 0x5000_0000_0000_000A = 2.315841784746329e+77

Input:  0x7FF0_0000_0000_0000 = +Inf
Output: 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 (others are possible)

Input:  0xFFF0_0000_0000_0000 = -Inf
Output: 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 (others are possible)

Input:  0x7FFC_0498_90A3_38C4 = NaN
Output: 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 (others are possible)

Input:  0x8000_0000_0000_0000 = -0
Output: 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 = +0

Input:  0x0000_0000_0000_0000 = +0
Output: 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 = +0

Input:  0x8A2B_7C82_413E_D451 = -1.1173031443752871e-259
Output: 0x8A2B_7C82_413E_D451 = -1.1173031443752871e-259

Input:  0x000F_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF = 2.225073858507201e-308
Output: 0x000F_FFFF_FFFF_F000 = 2.2250738585051777e-308

Input:  0x0000_B815_7268_FDAF = 1e-309
Output: 0x0000_B815_A81D_0000 = 1.0000044514797e-309
```

---

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) scoring, [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/7981) forbidden.

Comment: Can you please define or add a reference to IEEE 754 binary64 bitstring?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 172 bytes

```
#define D double
i;D f(D x){unsigned a[]={0,0};D*A=&a;D c=0;do{for(i=0;i<32;++i){*a=*a&~(1<<i)|!!(a[1]&1<<(31-i))<<i;};c=fabs(x-*A)<fabs(x-c)?*A:c;}while(++a[1]);return c;}
```

(Almost) purely brute-force; takes about 24 minutes per run on my machine.

`f` is a function that takes a double and returns the closest palindromic double. It iterates over every palindromic 64-bit sequence (as a double), storing the closing one, and returns it at the end.

This solution uses gcc on Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit, on a little-endian 32-bit single-core Pentium 4 2.8 GHz CPU.

Explanation/Ungolfed:

```
int i;
double f(double x) {
    unsigned int a[]={0, 0}; // a 2-array of ints is much easier to maipulate bitwise
    double *A = &a; // than a double, so refer to the same memory
    // in two different ways, a as int[2], A as double*
    double current = 0.0;
    do {
        for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
            *a = ( *a&~(1<<i) )|( (!!( (a[1]&1)<<(31-i) ))<<i);
            // reverse the bits of the second half into the first half
            // (*a is shorter than a[0])
        }
        current = fabs(x-*A)<fabs(x-current) ? *A : current;
        // if *A is closer to x than current, replace c with *A
    } while (++a[1]);
    // do-while instead of while to ensure each value is tried
    // at UINT32_MAX, overflows to 0, ending the loop.
    return current;
}
```

A C float (binary32) version that takes ~0.0015% as long to run (about 0.02 seconds on my machine) because it checks 1/65536 as many values: (<s>185</s> 179 bytes)

```
#define F float
i;F f(F x){unsigned short a[]={0,0};F*A=&a;F c=0;do{for(i=0;i<16;++i){*a=*a&~(1<<i)|!!(a[1]&1<<(15-i))<<i;};c=fabsf(x-*A)<fabsf(x-c)?*A:c;}while(++a[1]);return c;}
```